# double Hodge star operator

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms, tensors

$\star$ is the Hodge star operator acting on differential $k$-*forms* on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ as below:

$$\star:Λ^k(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \to Λ^{n-k}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$$
$$\alpha \wedge (\star \beta) = \langle \alpha,\beta \rangle \omega$$

where $ \langle , \rangle $ denotes the inner product on $(n-k)-$vectors and $\omega$ is the preferred unit $n-$vectors. 
Can somebody explain why we have

> $$\star\star\omega=\left(-1\right)^{k\left(n-k\right)}\omega.$$

Comment: Think of $v = e_1\wedge \cdots \wedge e_k$, where $e_1, \cdots, e_k$ are orthonormal . What is $*v$ and $**v$?